# integrating mod-spdy with mod-mono

Tags: .net, apache, mono, spdy

Google is working on a new application level protocol for the web SPDY and there is an apache module mod-SPDY for it. My question is that is it possible to integrate mod-spdy with apache's mono module (for opening .net pages) so that pages written in .net can load over SPDY.
        If so, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

mod_spdy had been put on hold for a while but is now under active development. Please give it another try: http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

mod_spdy is dead code.  It was written back when SPDY was at version 1 and won't work with recent versions of Chrome: http://japhr.blogspot.com/2011/04/dont-bother-with-modspdy.html.

So unfortunately, if you want to use mono with SPDY, you will need to pursue alternatives (e.g. writing your own library for mono).